# How can I extract a X.509 DER certificate from a byte[]?

Tags: java

I have a byte array beginning with a (variable length) DER formatted X.509 certificate.

After the certificate there are more bytes containing irrelevant data.

How can I extract only the bytes belonging to the certificate from the byte array without knowing its length beforehand (I will be using Java)?

Comment: This is a Java coding question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about programming, with only indirect relevance of cryptography. It should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certificate must be encoded using the distinguished encoding rules, using the ASN.1 definition found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1).

First read the sequence tag (one byte, check if it has value `30` hex).

Now parse the DER length field. This is encoded as a single byte for values up to 128. For length of 128 to 256 there will be two bytes (`81 XX` in hex, where XX is the unsigned value). Then you get to two bytes for value length from 256 to 64KiB, encoded as `82 XX XX` in hex, again as big endian unsigned value. If the certificate is over 64KiB you may be in trouble, even if you can guess the next encoding of the length.

So now you should add the tag length (1), the length of the length encoding (probably 3 bytes) and the length of the value together. This will give you the size of the entire certificate. Read it into a buffer or invent some bounded input stream and give it to the [`getInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getInstance(java.io.InputStream)) factory method of `X509Certificate`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Note: don't go overboard with making this efficient; certificates are usually relatively small, and no modern computer will miss a few KiB of temporary buffer.